Как задать небольшую высоту столбца в библиотеке docx.shared
есть библиотека docx.shared с функцией Cm(), задающей высоту столбца в docx файле, но в ней есть ограничения на минимальную высоту столбца, то есть при аргумемнтах 0.5 и 1 высота в docx файле получается одинаковая.
Как можно обойти это?
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Pt, Cm

# Создаем новый документ
doc = Document()

# Данные для вставки в таблицу
data = [
    ["Строка 1", "Строка 2"],
    ["Строка 3", "Строка 4"],
    ["Строка 5", "Строка 6"],
    ["Строка 7", "Строка 8"]
]

# Создаем таблицу
table = doc.add_table(rows=0, cols=2)

# Функция для установки формата текста в ячейке
def set_cell_text(cell, text, font_size):
    run = cell.paragraphs[0].add_run(text)
    run.font.size = Pt(font_size)
    run.font.italic = True

for i, row_data in enumerate(data):
    row = table.add_row().cells
    for j, cell_data in enumerate(row_data):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            set_cell_text(row[j], cell_data, 11)
        else:
            set_cell_text(row[j], cell_data, 5)
    if i % 2 == 0:
        table.rows[i].height = Cm(5)
    else:
        table.rows[i].height = Cm(1)

# Сохраняем документ
doc.save('test3.docx')

